# Using a Textbox and DropdownList to update data in an SQL database

Tags: vb.net

Please help,

VB.Net code behind ASPX Form. I have an SQL table that has a PartSN and Model field. The PartSN can have two entries stored in the table. What I want to do is have the code select the PartSN when entered in textbox1 and only update with a True when the PartSN matches the dropdownlist text.

I am getting an error in the Update code here: `where "('" &** TextBox1.Text & "' =PartSN") , ('" & Dropdownlist1.Text & "' =Model")"`

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT PartSN FROM Table_Data WHERE '" _
     & TextBox1.Text & "' =(PartSN)"

cmd.CommandText = "Update Table_Data SET TestComplete = @TestComplete where "('" _
  & TextBox1.Text & "' =PartSN") , ('" & Dropdownlist1.Text & "' =Model")"

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

With cmd.Parameters
    .AddWithValue("@TestComplete", "True")
```

Comment: can you tell us what the error is, or do we have to guess?

Comment: The "(" is saying Expression Expected.

Comment: Sorry let me be exact:  "('" is saying Expression Expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have the pieces backwards in your SELECT statement's WHERE clause, you are doing this:

```
SELECT PartSN FROM Table_data
WHERE 'ABC' = (PartSN)
```

That is not valid SQL, you need to put the field name of the left-hand side of the equal expression, like this:

```
SELECT PartSN FROM Table_data
WHERE PartSN = 'ABC'
```

Now your code should look like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT PartSN FROM Table_Data WHERE PartSN = '" _
    & TextBox1.Text & "'"
```

---

> Note: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks, because the WHERE clause is using unchecked values from `Text` property of the text box. In other words, the user could enter malicious database commands in the text box of your page and it would be executed against the database, such as `';DROP TABLE users;--` or something like that.

Use parameterized SQL, like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT PartSN FROM Table_Data WHERE PartSN = @PartSN"
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PartSN", SqlDbTypes.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBox1.Text
```

> Note: You will need to change the length of your `@PartSN` field from 50 to whatever the length is in the database.

UPDATE:

You are using the incorrect syntax for `AND`ing together criteria in the `WHERE` clause of your `SELECT` statement.

You are doing the equivalent of this:

```
SELECT PartSN FROM Table_data
WHERE (PartSN = 'ABC'), (Model = 'ABC')
```

The Boolean logic for `WHERE` clauses uses the `AND` or `OR` syntax, like this:

```
SELECT PartSN FROM Table_data
WHERE PartSN = 'ABC' AND Model = 'ABC'
```

So to use the parameterized SQL solution from above, do this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT PartSN FROM Table_Data WHERE PartSN = @PartSN AND Model = @PartSN"
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PartSN", SqlDbTypes.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBox1.Text
```

> Note: You may want to consider changing the parameter to a better name than `@PartSN`, because it is being used to compare against both the `PartSN` column and `Model` column.

Comment: Thanks. I made the changes. I am still getting the error Expression Expected at the "('" in the statement: cmd.CommandText = "Update Table_Data SET TestComplete = @TestComplete where "('" _
  & TextBox1.Text & "' =PartSN") , ('" & Dropdownlist1.Text & "' =Model")"

Comment: @user3042017 - `PartSN` and `Model` are the column names, they need to be on the left-hand side of the equals sign; like this: `"SELECT PartSN FROM Table_Data WHERE PartSN = '" _
    & TextBox1.Text & "'"`. Also, a comma (`,`) is not how you AND together criteria in a WHERE clause. It should be this: `"SELECT PartSN FROM Table_Data WHERE PartSN = '" _
    & TextBox1.Text & "'" AND Model = '" _
    & TextBox1.Text & "'"`. See updated answer.

Comment: @user3042017 - great, glad it is working. If you feel this answer helped you, then feel free to accept the answer and up-vote the answer when you can. :-)